# Same session is getting attached to seperate internet explorer windows while login?

Tags: java, web-applications, httpwebrequest, httpsession

I do the login to my java based application with admin credentials in one internet explorer window. Now i open one more seperate IE window and give my application home url i.e http://localhost:8888/myxwiki/ . I see in this second i am directly getting logged in with admin credentials which is not correct. I should see login screen on this second window here.

Then i did debugging and found out with both IE windows   xwikicontext.getRequest().getSession() returning the same session( basically both sessions are having same session id). As per my understanding session is specific to browser window . so both windows(or request from diffent IE windows) should have different session  attached to them.

Not getting how come both request fired from seperate browser windows are having same session id.

Comment: Is the second window a "new window" or just the "new tab"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're identifying the current session using a cookie (such as the JSESSIONID cookie) then that cookie will be shared across all open browser windows.

If I open a new tab or new window for a given website, my expectation would be for it to preserve my current session. Why do you expect differently?

Comment: As per requirement there can be a scenario when two different users want to login from two separate windows. But right now i have to logout first one to do login for second user. I agree this wont be the case in most application but this is the requirement in my use case.

Comment: @MSach: If that's a requirement in your use case, then *you cannot use a cookie* to persist the session state.  You'll have to encode a session token (or just the current session variables) into the URL query string parameter or into a form that gets POSTed on every request.  I think the simplest approach would be to avoid using the `HttpSession` implementation entirely, and create a "pseudo-session" by passing along the necessary state on every request.  (This is a more RESTful approach anyway.)

Comment: @MSach: Your use case is a bit unusual, however.  You're really going to have more than one user *sitting at the same computer*, logged in to two separate windows at the same time?  If the users are on separate computers, or even just logged in separately to the same computer (e.g. via remote desktop) then the cookie storage will be isolated and users won't see each other's sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version of IE you are using, if it is IE 9, then the following might be of use to create a separate session:

**File -> New Session**

This will open a new IE window with a separate session. Great for troubleshooting.